# Binding Removes Particle System Vertex Weight Map

Tags: rigging, vertex-groups

I am using Auto-Rig Pro and have stumbled into an issue I can’t seem to resolve. I have a model with a beard created with a particle system and utilizing a vertex weight map for placement. When I set everything up in ARP, the “bind” process removes the vertex map of the beard completely and the particle system populates all over the body. I understand what is happening, just not sure how to avoid it?

I thought I may be able to bake or create a secondary UVMap for the beard area, but I just can’t figure it out. I tried the ARP online manual and have searched several blender forums, probably not looking for the correct wording. Any ideas or links to solve this?

Seeing how common this must be, I am going to guess there is a fairly straight forward and simple process to avoid this, I just can’t figure it out on my own. I was hoping I don’t have to duplicate the vertices as a mesh and separate the beard from the body?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my issue. There is a lock icon that allows you to lock that specific vertex group that is highlighted.